# Wrong syntax in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to write a query that takes a point, given to a player in a match event, multiply it by another column and then by 3, and then copy the result in the players table where the player already exists. 
There is an error but I can't find what's wrong. Can you help me, please, with solving this issue?

```
UPDATE
j7yh8_bl_match_events,
j7yh8_bl_players

SET
j7yh8_bl_players.player_points = SELECT COUNT(j7yh8_bl_match_events.e_id) * j7yh8_bl_match_events.ecount * 3,

WHERE
j7yh8_bl_match_events.player_id = j7yh8_bl_players.id AND j7yh8_bl_match_events.e_id = 5;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use a `join` with `update`.  Any aggregation functions, though, have to be in subqueries.

I'm not 100% sure that the expression is for calculating points.  It seems that something like this solves your problem:

```
UPDATE j7yh8_bl_players p LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT me.player_id, SUM(me.ecount) * 3 as points
        FROM j7yh8_bl_match_events me
        WHERE me.e_id = 5
        GROUP BY me.player_id
       ) me
       ON me.player_id = p.id
    SET p.player_points = me.points
```

Comment: That's great, Gordon. It works perfectly. Thank you very much for the clarification and the help!